# Showing $\{x\} + \{\frac{1}{x}\} \lt 1.5$ and other problems.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, contest-math

For any real number $x$, let $[x]$ be the greatest integer not exceeding $x$. We also define $\{x\}=x-[x]$. We now define the function:

$f(x)=\{x\}+\{\frac{1}{x}\}$.

(a) Prove that $f(x)<1.5$ for $x>0$, and $f(x)<2$ for $x<0$.

(b) Prove that there exists a real number $\alpha $ such that $f(\alpha)>\frac{ 4001}{2001}$.

Going through cases I am convinced of (a). But how do you prove it conclusively?

(b) presented more challenges, but do we show existence without finding such {a} value{s}? Or do we need to find  specific value of $\alpha$?

Comment: greatest integer NOT exceeding $x.$

Comment: Sorry, typo. I just fixed it.

Comment: To get braces in TeX, write `\{` and `\}`, or `\lbrace` and `\rbrace`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $x = n+f$, where $n \ge 1$ (wlog) and $0 \lt f \lt 1$, then $\{\frac{1}{x}\} = \frac{1}{x}$ then

$$\{x\} + \{\frac{1}{x}\} = f + \frac{1}{n+f}$$

which is an increasing (and continuous) function of $f$ in $(0, 1])$, for $n \ge 1$.

This you can show by considering $f(t) = n+t + \frac{1}{n+t}$, which is just $t + \frac{1}{t}$ in disguise (and we have $t \ge 1$ for our purposes).

The maximum occurs when you choose $n=f=1$, and since $f$ is never really $1$, the inequality is strict.

A similar argument can probably be put forward for the case $x \lt 0$, and continuity arguments will show existence without having to construct one.

Comment: What about if $n=0$   ($f>0$)   then $\{\frac{1}{x}\}\not=\frac{1}{x}$???

Comment: @JohnMarty: Either $x$ or $\frac{1}{x} \gt 1$, so we can choose our $x \gt 1$ without loss of generality (that is what I meant when I wrote wlog).

Comment: I see, thanks and sorry.

Comment: @JohnMarty: No worries. It is good to make sure things are correct :-)

Answer (score 3):

**For (B)**:

Proof by example:

$$f(-9.9999\times10^{-6})>\frac{4001}{2001}.$$

See [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x-floor%5Bx%5D%2B%281%2Fx%29-floor%5B1%2Fx%5D+for+x%3D-.0000099999) and then [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1.99998%3E4001%2F2001) for convincing. Note that this is certainly not a very enlightening proof.

Comment: My previous answer was careless. I've focused on something else in my answer now.